# Trying to improve a tag wiki item in the approval screen results in page not found

Tags: bug, status-completed

The title pretty much says it, but basically when I'm in the approval screen for edits and I want to improve a tag wiki, clicking the improve button results in a page not found. Doesn't seem to be a problem with clicking improve for post edits.

Comment: on meta or on the main site? we don't support editing tag wikis on metas for now.

Comment: @Jeff Atwood - Main site. I'm using Firefox 4.0 in case it's a potential browser issue.

Answer (score 1):

The bug is that it should not be showing you that button if you do not have full tag edit rights (which you get at 20k)

Just fixed it.

Comment: Ah, I see. A little unfortunate though because that flow will probably result in more rejects to tag wiki when the suggestion is close but not quite right. That'll up the churn a little.